# Access sd card slot through VM inside gnome-boxes

Tags: virtualization

I have installed gnome-boxes to test some other linux distributions. I 'd like to access my laptops sd card slot with them. Can I do that with gnome-boxes? Or with configuring qemu or libvirtd underneath?

System info:

```
$ apt policy gnome-boxes 
gnome-boxes:
  Installed: 3.28.1-1
  Candidate: 3.28.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.1-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I have tried clicking the properties option while the VM was running but nothing in the Devices and Shares tab looked like an sd card.

Comment: Hmm. I suppose you could do a PCI passthrough with libvirtd, but I don't know if GNOME Boxes will do that. But any of them can share the media once it's mounted.